# problem in showing correct mysql concatenation

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation

i have two mysql tables which are linked together and i need to show my category list

**table_stories**

```
sid    ||   title   ||   time      ||  hometext  ||  associated
1      ||   test    ||  2010-07-19 ||  text----  ||  8-14-
```

**table_topics**

```
topicid     ||  topicname  ||  slug
1           ||  car        ||  car  
4           ||  wall       ||  wall  
8           ||  benz       ||  benz  
14          ||  ford       ||  ford
```

now if i use this query to fetch story list :

```
 LEFT JOIN table_topics AS nto ON 
 (CONCAT(' ',COALESCE(ns.associated,'-'),'-') LIKE CONCAT('%',nto.topicid,'-%'))
```

then **output** would show stories with topic id  :  **8 , 4 , 14**

you see that it counts topic id **4** as similar as **14**

please concider that i cant change mysql table structure and i should find a work around for this problem

Comment: Something like adding a '-' before CONCAT and replacing the first '%' with '%-'...

Comment: if i replace first % with %- then topic id 8 wont be read because there is no - before it , check the schema of table_stories and associated field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a combination of the [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) and [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) functions:

```
LEFT JOIN table_topics AS nto ON FIND_IN_SET(nto.topicid, REPLACE(ns.associated, '-', ','))
```

Comment: ... for weird database schema ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd do the following:
Split associated on '-', check if the topic id is IN the resulting array.